# How to call a function outside the FilesInterceptor scope ? - Nest JS

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs

I'm working on NestJS I follow guides from the internet to do this. It can work normally.

But I want to get a **productBrand** to be used as a directory path. I need to get it by calling the **productRepository** to get the **productBrand**. But inside the **destination: (req, file, cb) => {
}** it does not know the productRepository or any function outside this scope

```
constructor(
  @InjectRepository(Product)
  private readonly productRepository: Repository<Product>
) {}


@Post('product/image/:productId/')
@UseInterceptors(
    FilesInterceptor('files', 1, {
      storage: diskStorage({
        destination: (req, file, cb) => {
            const productId = req.params.productId;
            const product = await this.productRepository.find({
              where: {id: productId},
              select: { productBrand:true }
            });

            const directory = `../products/${product.productBrand}`
            cb(null, directory)
        },
        filename: function (req, file, callback) {
            callback(null, file.originalname);
        }
      }),
    }),
  )
  @ApiBody({
    required: true,
    type: "multipart/form-data",
    schema: {
      type: "object",
      properties: {
        files: {
          type: "string",
          format: "binary",
        },
      },
    },
})
@ApiConsumes("multipart/form-data")
async uploadProductImage(
  @Param('productId') productId,
  @Res() res:Response,
  @UploadedFiles(
      new ParseFilePipeBuilder()
      .addFileTypeValidator({
          fileType: /(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$/,
      })
      .addMaxSizeValidator({ maxSize: 20242880 })
      .build({
          errorHttpStatusCode: HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY
      })
  ) files: Array<Express.Multer.File>
){
  //logic to save to a database...
}
```

How can I call **productRepository** ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use either a factory method or a configuration class for [Async Configuration of `MulterModule`](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/file-upload).

Here's an example on how to do this if you are going to create a config class for configuring Multer.

```js
@Injectable()
class MulterConfigService implements MulterOptionsFactory {
  constructor(@InjectRepository(Product) private readonly productRepository: Repository<Product>) {}

  createMulterOptions(): MulterModuleOptions {
    return {
      storage: diskStorage({
        destination: async (req, file, cb) => {
          const { productId } = req.params;
          const product = await this.productRepository.find({
            where: { id: productId },
            select: { productBrand: true },
          });

          const directory = `../products/${product.productBrand}`;
          cb(null, directory);
        },
        filename(req, file, callback) {
          callback(null, file.originalname);
        },
      }),
    };
  }
}
```

Provide `MulterConfigService` properly on your feature module or your `AppModule` if it is global.

```js
@Module({
  imports: [
    MulterModule.registerAsync({
     useClass: MulterConfigService,
    }),
    ...
  ],
  ...
})
export class YourFeatureModule{}
```

Cheers  !!!

Comment: Is it going to override others file upload API ? Because I have another API use the different path.

Comment: I believe so. If you want to have different configurations for different routes, I guess you can handle it in 2 ways. You can add a `switch-case` (or `if-else`) logic in your `destination` function to configure it based on different `req`. I believe `req` will have properties in it so you can determine which path it will hit. Alternatively, you can create your own metadata to decorate each path based on which configuration of Multer you want (https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/execution-context#reflection-and-metadata). I havent' worked with Multer that much but the design should be similar.